# XML Schema 1.1 not recognizing 'assert' or 'assertion'

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

I am trying to use the following in an *XSD*

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" >
<xs:element name="dimension">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="height" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:assert test="@height = @width"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I know assert/assertion are part of XML Schema 1.1 but not 1.0. However everything I have read indicates the *namespace* is the same for both: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

A minor problem is that the program I am using to write the Schema (Microsoft Visual Studio) does not recognize the 'assert' element, saying the 'the element *complexType* in namespace (...) has invalid child element 'assert'.

The main problem is that when I actually try to validate an XML against this schema, using xmllint, it throws up an error saying

```
" element assert: Schemas parser error : Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}complexType': The content is not valid. Expected is (annotation?, (simpleContent | complexContent | ((group | all | choice | sequence)?, ((attribute | attributeGroup)*, anyAttribute?))))
```

Is 1.1 simply not recognized by xmllint/visual studio, despite being pointed to the 1.1 namespaces?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To process an XSD 1.1 schema you need an XSD 1.1 schema processor. Microsoft does not supply one (they seem to have given up implementing new W3C XML specifications). As far as I am aware the  only XSD 1.1 processor available on the .NET platform is Saxonica's.

Comment: Thank you! I am new to xml schema, but would have thought the processor would just pull down the latest definition from the namespace you point it to.

Are there any 1.1 XSD compatible editors for linux?

Comment: No, you can't expect a processor developed in 1994 to implement a specification published in 2013. oXygen is an editor that runs on linux and supports XSD 1.1

Comment: Oxygen does not support 1.1, it is throwing error on assert and assertion. I am running eclipse oxygen on ubuntu 16 linux so I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: oXygen does support XSD 1.1 see for example https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/20.1/ug-editor/topics/schema-1-1-support.html