# XML schema 1.1 assertions in C#

Tags: c#, xsd

I'm validating some xml files with the following xml schema:

```
        String xsdMarkup = 
          "[...]

           <xsd:complexType name='connectionType'>
                <xsd:attribute name='SourceElement' type='guidType' use='required' />
                <xsd:attribute name='TargetElement' type='guidType' use='required' />
                <xsd:attribute name='GUID' type='guidType' use='required' />
                <xsd:assert test='@SourceElement == 0' />
           </xsd:complexType>

           [...]
          ";

        XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schemas.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsdMarkup)));
        Console.WriteLine("Validating doc ...");
        docToValidate.Validate(schemas, (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            valid = false;
        }, true);
```

I just wanted to introduce some assert tags in order to have more powerful validation. But this leads to the exception:

> System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException: The http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:assert-element is not supported in this context.

What I don't know right now is whether...

1. I used the assert-element in the wrong place inside the xsd
2. The http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-Namespace doesn't support version 1.1 of XML Schema and thereby assert-elements
3. C# XmlSchemaSet doesn't know how to deal with assert elements

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML Schema 1.1 not recognizing 'assert' or 'assertion'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573894/xml-schema-1-1-not-recognizing-assert-or-assertion)

Comment: Bit of a pain that. Had thoughts of not having to use schematron. Oh well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .NET implementation of XSD schemas handle only version 1.0 and not version 1.1 - hence it does not support `assert`.

Comment: There is always Saxon, of course ... Just because you're using C# doesn't mean the MS tools are your only options.