# How to do XML cross referencing?

Tags: xml, validation, xls, cross-reference, idref

I'm trying to do element cross reference in XML without success. Here's my schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:complexType name="guestType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="address" type="addressType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>
    <xs:attribute name="ref" type="xs:IDREF"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="addressType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="houseNumber" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="roadName" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" />
    <xs:attribute name="ref" type="xs:IDREF"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="event">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="time" type="xs:time"/>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
           <xs:element name="guest" type="guestType"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The code for the XML document is:

```
<eventxmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='src/tests/newXmlSchema.xsd'>
    <time>14:00:00</time>
    <guest id="1">
        <name>John</name>
        <address id="add1">
           <houseNumber>222</houseNumber>
           <roadName>Meat Street</roadName>
        </address>
    </guest>
    <guest id="2">
        <name>Henry</name>
        <address ref="add1"/>
    </guest>
</event>
```

I'm using Netbeans to validate. The validation throws an error in:

```
<address ref="add1"/>
```

The error is:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'address' is not complete. One of '{houseNumber}' is expected.
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

PS. I couldn't find any previous question with something as basic as this. The others were using XLS, is this what I should be using?

Comment: You haven't made any of the sub-elements optional. The way your schema is laid out, your sequence `{houseNumber, roadName}` is mandatory.

Comment: assuming you'll resolve the 'ref' to 'id' in your own code, you could make address a sequence of choices. 1st sequence is the normal content with ID attribute, 2nd sequence would be the 'REF' attribute without child elements.

Comment: @dcsohl I tried adding minOccurs="0" and maxOccurs="unbounded" to make them optional but it didn't work. Is there any other way?

Comment: Having played around with your XML i was painfully reminded of the limitations of XSD 1.0. You can do what you want but need 'asserts' which require XSD 1.1 which is not supported by .Net XML library. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331144/xml-schema-1-1-assertions-in-c-sharp for more info on asserts