# Sequence of elements with same name but different argument value

Tags: xml, xsd

I have to validate following XML (used in thirdparty REST service) against XML Schema.
There are some `Key` elements that are obligatory for service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
  <Details>
    <Key name="ONE"   label="a" value="11"/>
    <Key name="THREE" label="c" value="33"/>
    <Key name="TWO"   label="b" value="22"/>
  </Details>
</Data>
```

Is there any way (using XML Schema) to force element `Details` to contain all three `Key` elements with name attribute set to specific values, respectively `ONE`, `TWO` and `THREE`? No particular order of `Key` elements should be required.

Also additional `Key` elements should be possible:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
  <Details>
    <Key name="ONE"   label="a" value="11"/>
    <Key name="THREE" label="c" value="33"/>
    <Key name="TWO"   label="b" value="22"/>

    <Key name ="OPTIONAL1" label="opt1" value="opt1"/>
    <Key name ="OPTIONAL2" label="opt2" value="opt2"/>
  </Details>
</Data>
```

Is there any chance to do it using schema? Please help!

Comment: With [xsd 1.1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15573894/314291) you can surely do this by `assert` ing that all three attribute values are present, or, if they must be unique, that the `count` of each of the values must appear exactly once. Or better still, [`xsd:all`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12012599/314291)